# socket.io why assert(false)

Tags: c++, c++11, socket.io

I am developing a program in C++ to communicate over Socket.IO and I am referring the [console example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/examples/Console/main.cpp). At line 77-78 we have the following statements :

```
string user = data->get_map()["username"]->get_string();
string message = data->get_map()["message"]->get_string();
```

If I go to [sio_message.h](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/src/sio_message.h) on line 101 we have definition of map method as  given bellow. On line 103 their is an `assert(false)` statement which is causing my program to fail. Can anyone enlighten me why this `assert(false)` statement is present.

```
virtual std::map<std::string,message::ptr>& get_map()
{
     assert(false);  ///why this???
     static std::map<std::string,message::ptr> s_empty_map;
     s_empty_map.clear();
     return s_empty_map;
}
```

My Code :

```
void Socket_IO::receive_listener(std::string const&name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp)
{

    spdlog::info("Data Recieved : " + data->get_map()["message"]->get_string()); // I am getting an Socket.IO exception here
    spdlog::info("Message Name : " + name);
}
```

Comment: Aside from that assert it's just returning an empty map. It looks like they don't want anyone to call the function. Perhaps it's intended to be called from a subclass that overrides the function with an actual implementation?

Comment: It looks this method is supposed to be overridden. Are you sure `data` refers to a subclass of `message` ?

Comment: @Botje, data is an shared pointer of type message class (line41 in sio_message.h)

Comment: `get_map` is a virtual method, so you cannot tell this just from looking at the code. What is the type **at runtime**?

Comment: Writing `spdlog::info("Data Recieved : " + data->get_string())` in place of `spdlog::info("Data Recieved : " + data->get_map()["message"]->get_string())` works seamlessly. However `get_string` method also has `assert(false)` line 63.

Comment: @Botje, I fired `std::string(typeid(data).name())` and I am getting the following output `class std::shared_ptr<class sio::message>`

Comment: Close. you need `typeid(*data)` or somesuch. There is one subclass of `message` that does not `assert` for `get_string`, which is `string_message`...

Comment: Yup, executing `std::string(typeid(data).name())` return  `class sio::string_message`. sio::string_message has a getString method. Thanks now my understanding is clear.